# Restore .bak file with docker MSSQL server in MAC OS

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, docker, ssms, azure-data-studio

I am using the docker MS-SQL server latest version and trying to restore the database (.bak) file using Azure data studio. But not able to find the physical location in MAC

[image]

As per the Azure data studio it points the data to the `/var/opt/mssql/data` however, we can't find the location on the MAC OS.

Docker SQL server command that I used to run the image

```
docker run --name MsSql -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Comment: is it possible to run sql server in mac os either using docker or normally ? just a curiosity question..

Answer (score 0):

using the below command solve my issue, I have to mount the volume with the container volumn

```
docker run --name MsSql -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=FeteBird@sql' -p 1433:1433 -v /var/opt/mssql/data:/var/opt/mssql/data -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```